# Maximal solution set of equation in $\mathbb Z/p$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, finite-fields

Consider the following equation: $\lambda_1(x_1+x_2+\dotsc +x_t)+\lambda_2(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsc +x_t^2) + \dots + \lambda_t(x_1^t+x_2^t+\dotsc +x_t^t) = -1$ mod $p$. Here the $x_i$ are pairwise distinct and from $\{1,2,\dotsc, n\}$ and $t < n/2$. Moreover, $n\ll p$ (think of $n$ of order $log(p)$ at most), and $t$ and $n$ are fixed of course. My question is: Can we choose the $\lambda_i$ from $\mathbb{Z}/p$ such that the above equation is satisfied for all possible tuples $(x_1,\dotsc,x_t)$ (as defined above)? If not, can we quantify the maximal number of such tuples (say, find a good upper bound) from all possible $\binom{n}{t}$ tuples?

Comment: I'm a little bit curious about the origin of this constraint. Shedding more light to that would also add useful context to the question. It looks like at least one reviewer has such concerns. @All: This does not look like a homework assignment at all :-)

Comment: Dear Jyrki. No, this has nothing to do with a homework assignment. The question arose from the following question: Let's say you have a polynomial of degree $t$: $f(X) = a_0+a_1X+\dotsc+a_tX^t$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p[X]$. Any such polynomial is determined by $t+1$ distinct points, let's say $x$-coordinates coming from the set $M = \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$. If any of these coefficients is already fixed, then you only need $t$ points that determine $f$, since the generalized/lacunary Vandermonde matrix is still invertible if the points are from $M$ e.g. [To be continued].

Comment: But what if for instance $a_0$ is a linear combination of the remaining $a_i$, say $a_0 = \lambda_1a_1+\dotsc+\lambda_t a_t$. Is the resulting polynomial still determined by any $t$ points from $M$? Or can I find $\lambda_i$ such that $f$ is never determined by $t$ points? Now you can build the corresponding matrix (such as the Vandermonde matrix) and the question is when it is of rank $t$ for some $x_1,\dotsc,x_t \in M$. I wrote it down and used the Matrix determinant lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma and got the above equation in my initial post. [To be continued]

Comment: What is says is that the matrix I got is not of full rank (and thus those corresponding $t$ points $x_j$ do not determine the polynomial fully) iff the initial equation is satisfied. The question "are there $\lambda_i$ such that the equation is satisfied for all possible $t$-tupel from $M$" is equivalent to "no $t$ points from $M$ determine $f$ fully". This question comes ultimately from my cryptography research. And therefore it would also be nice to know what is the worst case scenario. And also what if the $\lambda_i$ would be picked randomly from $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first part only. This is impossible.

Let $M=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\subset\Bbb{F}_p=\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$. Let
$f(x)=\lambda_1x+\lambda_2x^2+\cdots+\lambda_tx^t\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. Your constraint is that the sum of the values of $f$
$$
S(f,U):=\sum_{x\in U}f(x)=-1\qquad(*)
$$
over any subset $U\subset M$ such that $|U|=t$.

The constraint $(*)$ forces the restriction of the polynomial function $f$ to the set $M$ to be a constant. For if $x,y\in M$ are distinct we can choose a set $U'$ to consist of some $t-1$ elements of $M$ distinct from both $x$ and $y$. Then
$$f(x)-f(y)=S(f,U'\cup\{x\})-S(f,U'\cup\{y\})=(-1)-(-1)=0,$$
so $f(x)=f(y)$.

Therefore the polynomial $f(x)-f(1)$ vanishes whenever $x\in M$. But this polynomial has degree $\le t$, so it cannot have $n>t$ zeros in the field $\Bbb{F}_p$ unless it is constant zero. Therefore $\lambda_j=0$ for all $j$, in violation of $(*)$.

---

I cannot say much about the upper bound. For low enough degree polynomials $f$ the sums $S(f,U)$ become almost random elements of the field $\Bbb{F}_p$, so we expect the constraint to be satisfied with probability roughly $1/p$, and expect roughly $\binom nt/p$ cases of it being equal to $-1$. Exponential sums may or may not give a useful error term, but I don't have the time to think about it.

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much! Nice one! So we now know at least that it can't be satisfied for all $t$-tupels from $M$.
But what do you mean with "low enough degree polynomial $f$"? We already know that $t$ is at most of the order of $log(p)$. Is that enough, or do you want $\lambda_i = 0$ for say $i \geq 2$? And you say that for randomly chosen $\lambda_i$ and low enough degree $f$, the probability is roughly $1/p$ to get the equation satisfied?

Comment: But in the case $\lambda_i = 0$ for $i\geq 2$ we have $\lambda_1(x_1+\dotsc+x_t) = -1$ and the sum $S_1= x_1+\dotsc+x_t$ ranges from $t(t+1)/2$ to roughly $t(t+1)/2 +t^2$. And therefore, the sum $S_1$ is constant on roughly $\binom{n}{t}/t^2$ tupels. And if we choose $\lambda_1$ appropriately, we expect the prob to be $1/t^2$ so that the equation is satisfied.

Comment: True, a very narrow range changes the game.

Comment: But can we say anything about the solution set if the $\lambda_i$ are chosen uniformly at random?